# Access VBA RunSQL Error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to insert into a table the top x records from a query data-set. However I keep getting the run-time error '3061' Too few parameters. Expected 1. I've tried a few things but it doesn't make any difference.

```
Private Sub UpdateGA_Click()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rounds As Integer
Dim playerid As Long

Set dbs = CurrentDb

rounds = Me.NoOfScores.Value
playerid = Me.lngPlayerID.Value

strSQL = "INSERT INTO [tbl_TopRounds] ( [lngPlayerID], [lngRoundID],  [dblPlayedTo], [dteRoundDate]) " & _
" SELECT TOP " & Me.NoOfScores.Value & " [lngPlayerID], [lngRoundID], [dblPlayedTo], [dteRoundDate] FROM qry_LastRounds" & _
" WHERE [lngPlayerID] = " & Me.lngPlayerID.Value & _
" ORDER BY [dblPlayedTo], [dteRoundDate] DESC;"

dbs.Execute strSQL

End Sub
```

I'm expecting that x (based on a form parameter) records will be written to the tbl_TopRounds.

[VB Error on executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2b5i.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this error means that you made a mistake in field name. Set breakpoint on last command, run the sub, open immediate window and type `?strSQL`. Copy received SQL text and try to run it in query builder, it will show column name which doesn't exist in the table. The error may be in the query `qry_LastRounds`, check it first by opening

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Sergey. When I add a breakpoint and run the sub it pops up a dialog box requesting a Macro Name. I'm setting the break point at dbs.Execute.

Comment: Just click UpdateGA button

Comment: Thanks but the query runs ok when I do this. It inserted 4 records into the tbl_TopRounds which is what was expected.

Comment: The ?strSQL produced the following: INSERT INTO [tbl_TopRounds] ( [lngPlayerID], [lngRoundID], [dblPlayedTo], [dteRoundDate])  SELECT TOP 4 [lngPlayerID], [lngRoundID], [dblPlayedTo], [dteRoundDate] FROM qry_LastRounds WHERE [lngPlayerID] = 33487 ORDER BY [dblPlayedTo], [dteRoundDate] DESC;
Which ran ok in a query builder.

Comment: Hi Sergey, I changed the code to DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL and it worked fine. The Execute must have been expecting an optional constant? Many thanks for your help though.

Comment: That's interesting. The difference between RunSQL and Execute is evaluating of parameters, see the answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/71392d23-867f-444f-a333-874b3f7eaea8/docmdrunsql-vs-dbexecute?forum=accessdev). `Execute` is more preferable way, so I would investigate why Execute requires parameter, check the query first. Also add `dbFailOnError` option as second parameter to Execute.

Comment: This might shine some light on the behavior of .Execute: [RunSQL vs Execute](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php?title=RunSQL_vs_Execute&diff=5921&oldid=5918)